# Getting an instance's attributes from a related instance

Tags: python, class, oop, reference

Why is it that I cannot access the attribute of an object as seen in the following example? (raises an error)

```
class X(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.y = Y(self)
    self.variable = 5

class Y(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        print self.parent.variable

my_instance = X()
```

Error raised: `AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'variable'`

Shouldn't `variable` be accessible to the instance of `Y` that is created when `X` is initialized?

Comment: The `__init__` code is run in order from top to bottom.  You aren't setting `variable` until *after* you create the `Y` object.

Comment: @BrenBarn: answers should be `Answers`, not `comment`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move self.variable = 5 to before self.y = Y(self). When Y is initialized, variable has yet to be set in the parent. Since it is not a class attribute (it is defined only for the instance) it does not exist until then.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating before adding/initializing the `variable` attribute. It will have no knowledge of the variable unless again instantiated or swapped as the other answer mentioned.